# Is Deep Linking supported in Mobile Push(SFMC)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, react-native

Is there deep linking support in mobile push?
I didn't find anything related in the documentation.

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_mobilepush.htm&type=5

In mobile push and in Jorney Builder there are fields where it is possible to send a link, when I receive the push I can take this value and manipulate it in the App.
Can I say that these fields are similar?
If they are not similar, which ones could I use for such a function?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deeplinking 100% is supported, however, there's not a single line of code in the SDK that enables it or prevents it. It's entirely up to the application developer to add the functionality to their application.

Comment: Hello Bill Mote, i edited the ask, could you review? thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking in your updated question.

Comment: Our marketing team for sending push notifications uses both mobile push and jorney builder in the campaigns built in SFMC.
We are implementing the notification functionality in stages, at this point seeing what the deep link notifications look like in both of the products I mentioned above.
So, we need to understand if the fields that I have marked on the photos correspond to the fields that add the deep link to the notification in each SFMC product. Would these be the fields?

Comment: The SDK does not handle deeplinks. Your application does. Not a single line of code is required by the SDK to support deeplinks. You create a schema in your application's manifest and you write the activity/service that will handle the URL when it is clicked as part of the notification.

Comment: `Media` is for images, not URLs/Actions. Look at "OpenDirect" for push notifications. For InApp Messages you have identified the correct place to put your URL.